# how to clean out a htc desire 626s

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I have a Boost Mobile HTC Desire 626s. I just upgraded to a ZTE Warp Elite. When I 1st got the HTC phone I got the phone rooted. The phone worked fine except for 1 annoying problem. Every few days a bar would popup saying a "system update" was needed. The only 2 options were "later (as in doing the install later)" and "install". I keep hitting later. I got tired of seening that popup every few days so I hit install. Big mistake.  The phone is now stuck in a sys update loop. It says download complete, starting to unzip the file. But the unzip does nothing then error's out after a while. I spoke to Boost Mobile today. And even bigger mistake. All the hard master reset did was wipe out my pictures, phone list and so on (all that stuff is backed up on my laptop already, no lose there). But the hard reset didn't fix the system update loop problem. And now the phone is stuck in a basic phone activation loop as well.  I am trying to setup the phone so my nephew can use the phone like a tablet for now. And if he keeps his grades up in school I will activate his phone on my cell phone plain with his own number. If I can clear up this mess and get the phone working right again.

I 1st used the unlocker that I found on the HTC web page, then I used Kingo Root to root the phone. The factory reset line is missing from the download mode. Also if I go to bootloader > boot to recovery mode. The phone boots out to normal phone mode.  I am stuck and I don't know how to fix this.  A point of interest I an a Windows tech. I have been fixing Windows based laptops and desktops for years as well as 2 way radios and tv's.

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to do the same thing as if you had a failed update on a non-rooted phone.  Go to HTC, grab the utility meant for communicating between your computer and phone.  Then download that and a factory Android zip and use the utility to flash that to the phone.

It took me a little bit, but I seem to have dug out the official HTC info on this.

You want to go to the **Manual system update instructions** section on this page and follow those instructions.  If for whatever reason you can not get the utility to see the phone and flash the factory zip you are SOL without a custom recovery or ability to boot to the OS there is not anything else you can do.  You will want to send it in for warranty replacement if you have that going (contact Boost).  with the custom recovery gone and the OS stuck in a boot loop with the official OTA version (NEVER apply OTA updates or you will lose root and your custom recovery EVERY time).  If you hate the notification pop-up you should look for a ROM that says it is a rooted factory ROM with the update check modified so it does not check for updates.  Otherwise ALWAYS say update later and ignore it.

Here's the HTC info page: http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-desire-626s-boost/news/

Also factory reset is gotten to through the recovery menu and NOT download mode.  Factory reset only removes saved user data and does nothing to the actual system files themselves.  To do that you need to actually download the zip from HTC and use their utility to flash it.

IF YOU STILL HAVE THE CUSTOM RECOVERY (TWRP OR CLOCKWORK) YOU CAN FLASH ANY ROM ZIP MEANT FOR THE CDMA VERSION OF THE 626s WHICH I FOUND A FEW LISTED ON XDA FORUMS UNDER THE 626 SECTION (here's a stock ROM you can flash with custom recovery (and if needed grab microsd card plug in to computer reader to load the file on it then plug in to phone and restart to recovery): http://forum.xda-developers.com/desire-626/development/rom-flashable-stock-htc-626s-debloated-t3293602

Again, this only works if you have the custom recovery and NOT the stock recovery.

Comment: On the OS, I forgot to add. The operating system is not completely gone. I can bring up the home page and run app's that don't require access to the internet. But the boot loop will interrupt what ever is running and after the zip error message the phone restarts it's self and reboots.

Comment: When you say "if the utility can't see the phone to flash factory zip" Is there a manual way to flash the factory zip file? Were can I find a custom recovery prog that can boot the the OS if I need it?

Comment: I have the HTC Sync Manager software downloaded and installed. The sync manager is synced up with the phone and ready to go.  I also found at the HTC webpage RUU_A32E_WHL_M60_DESIRE_SENSE70_SPCS_MR_Sprint_WWE_2.27.651.6.exe.  If this works. Then that's it? The job is done?

Comment: The sync manager is working and syncing up to the phone. But the instructions say to "Once the device is properly recognized on the PC, locate the HTC Desire™ ROM Update that you downloaded. Double-click on the file to launch the system update wizard.
     Follow all of the system update wizard instructions shown on your PC. "  , The file I downloaded is    RUU_A32E_WHL_M60_DESIRE_SENSE70_SPCS_MR_Sprint_WWE_2.27.651.6.exe.  When I dbl click on the RUU file it makes my laptop go nuts, lock up and then a blue screen crash.

Comment: well you will need to run that it looks like.  Make sure you downloaded the correct file and could try downloading again if it had an issue during download maybe it is corrupt.  You will probably also need to right click it and choose run as admin for it to work correctly.  You can try using compatibility mode (right click file and there should be a tab for it) and try selecting Windows XP if for some reason it does not run when you right click and select run as admin.

Comment: Is Sprint your carrier?  Make sure this file is exactly what you need and not for maybe  a different phone.  If you have anti virus (including Windows Defender) you may also need to disable that temporarily until this is done (usually in settings disable any auto file scanners).

Comment: My carrier is Boost Mobile, a sub of Sprint.   I am going to have to go with a custom recovery system because this boot loop that is in the phone cycles about every 7 minutes. When the boot loop cycles it cuts the USB connection to the laptop. And when I run the RUU as admin. It takes about 5 minutes for the box to come up asking if I want to run it as an admin.

Comment: I have a self booting (ISO) cd in Linux format for a prog called Slitaz, Cwm that is a left over from my old ZTE Warp 4G phone. Can this be used to flash the right RUU to the Desire 626s?

Comment: Mike are you online?

Comment: :-D  The phone is DONE.  The bootloop is GONE. The phone is re-setup as a new stock (non-rooted) phone, and is ready for activation. That's what I want for my nephew's  phone.  I don't want him to have root access. He is just curious enough to go into the root files if he had access and mess them up.  Anyways it is done.  YIPPEE, HOORAY!!!!

Comment: Glad I could get you back to a working condition.  Yeah what you just did is what we like to call the unbrick procedure.  This basically requires a factory image and utility you connect the usb to the phone and use utility to flash the factory image.  Once done it will be just like you got it out of the box when you first bought it (maybe a little different since it probably is a newer version of Android but thats what that phone now looks like out of a box).   Sorry I was not online earlier for you I can be random some times.

Comment: If you don't mind please mark my answer as correct so I get me some points please (I'm new round here :-) ).

Comment: I don't see any way to mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Someone got it if you didn't find it.  I am not sure either as I only had one question soo far not fully answered.  Glad I got you working again.